# Can't add new sections into app.config

Tags: c#, web-config, config, app-config

Each time I try to add a very basic section into app.config I get the following error:

```
Configuration system failed to initialize.
```

I have looked at the variety of articles but none of those has helped so far.
Any ideas what is going wrong?

**Edit:**

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="Test" type="TestType"/>
  </configSections>

  <Test>  

  </Test>
```

Comment: You'll need to post the section you're trying to add.

Comment: Can you post what you're trying to add to the app.config file in context.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, please see the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you define a configuration section handler? Here is a tutorial:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309045

**Edit:** (Based on your updated question)
I recommend to specify the type with the [fully qualified assembly name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx).

Comment: Hey, yes I have just came across few articles online. I have moved configSection to the top of the file and I get the following exception: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Test: Could not load type 'TestType' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral)... I guess now I have to figure out what type it should have.

Comment: just specify the type with "type, assembly, version, culture, public key token" (the link about fully qualified assembly name is not as good as I would like)

Comment: maybe this makes it clearer: http://threeisit.com/post/Fully-qualified-assembly-names.aspx

Comment: Is there a simpler workaround? What are the chances of assembly, version, culture or public key token changing?

Comment: you probably get away with just specifying "type, assembly", but as the other values in your case probably never change... why not just specify them as well

Comment: Have been sat with this for hours. I either can't load an assembly, or assembly gets loaded, but when I try and read data from mycustomerconfig.xml I get a null...

Answer (score 1):

Read/Write App.config with .NET 2.0/Enterprise [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810043157/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx)